# Errorboundary doesn't capture errors when simple component calls dictionary which errors

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have the default error boundary mentioned in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) and I have a dictionary that would normally be filled with functions I can execute.
I've specifically created a test case below which will error out because a particular function doesn't exist in the dictionary, I'm expecting the error boundary to catch this, however, it doesn't appear to work, what might be going on?

The simple component that should error out, but parts of it should still render:

```
export const App = () => {
    return 
          <ErrorBoundary>
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingIcon/>}>
              <div>this should show #1</div>
              <ErrorBoundary>
               <SimpleComponent />
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
});


export const SimpleComponent: FC = ({}) => {
    const mydictionary: Dictionary<() => JSX.Element> = {};

    return (
        <div>
           stuff that should still render. #2
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <div>{mydictionary['nonexistentvalue']()}</div>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The error boundary:

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<{}, { hasError: any }> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hasError: false };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
        // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
        console.log('err', error);
        return { hasError: true };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error: any, errorInfo: any) {
        this.setState({ hasError: true });
        console.error('Help', error, errorInfo);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            // You can render any custom fallback UI
            return <h1>Something went wrong here.</h1>;
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

What I get is just the single `Something went wrong here.` on the page.

Comment: The docs state that boundaries can only catch errors from child _components_. Does `<ErrorBoundary />` need to full be outside the `SimpleComponent` component?

Comment: Error boundaries Catch when a component throws a new error, then that error will bubble up to the error boundary. I believe the way you have it if an error would have been thrown on the mydictionary would emanate from SimpleComponent, so the ErrorBoundary which is beneath it wouldn't pick it up.

Comment: Unfortunately these didn't work. I'll update my post to include what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `SimpleComponent` with your `ErrorBoundary` component. When `SimpleComponent` will be wrapped error boundary component should work correctly. Docs says that error boundary component can handle only issues of children components wrapped with this error boundary component. On the same level it won't work.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <SimpleComponent/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I'll update my post to include what I did.